# JQM 1.4 beta persistent navbar not keeping active state class for links

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm facing an issue with the latest beta release of jQuery Mobile. I'm trying to implement a fixed persistent footer navbar, the persistent part is working but whenever I click a link and navigate to another page the `ui-btn-active` class is lost and no link appears selected.

Here's a demo fiddle that reproduces the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/DgdMg/2/

And here's the complete markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0-beta.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("[data-role='header'],[data-role='footer']").toolbar();
            $.mobile.window.triggerHandler("throttledresize");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
            <h1>My fixed header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Page 1 content goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page-2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Page 2 content goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#page-2">Page 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed the instruction from [the demos in the docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-beta.1/dist/demos/toolbar-persistent/footer-persist-a.html) (which don't seem to be complete) and placed the footer outside the page container. I tried adding `.ui-state-persist` to the first link and to both links but it didn't produce any effect and since even the demos are not working correctly I'm not sure how to proceed.

I would appreciate any insight on how to keep the `ui-btn-active` class for the clicked link.

Comment: It looks like navbar widget is not 100% complete. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6337?source=cc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found this on jQM updated demo page. Adding `.ui-btn-active` for external fixed toolbars depends on `data-role=page`'s `data-title` attribute.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-1" data-title="Page 1">
```

Navbar buttons text, should match `data-title` in order to determine which button should be updated with `.ui-btn-active`, as well as updating `data-role=header` title.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YzULS/)**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("[data-role='navbar']").navbar();
    $("[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']").toolbar();
});

// Update the contents of the toolbars
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function () {
    // Each of the four pages in this demo has a data-title attribute
    // which value is equal to the text of the nav button
    // For example, on first page: <div data-role="page" data-title="Info">
    var current = $(this).jqmData("title");
    // Change the heading
    $("[data-role='header'] h1").text(current);
    // Remove active class from nav buttons
    $("[data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
    // Add active class to current nav button
    $("[data-role='navbar'] a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() === current) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-btn-active");
        }
    });
});
```

> **Source:** http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/toolbar-fixed-persistent/

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess this means the active state won't work out the box for persistent toolbars and a "manual" update would be needed.

Comment: Exactly. JQM team is going to refactor navbar widget, not to mention that external fixed toolbars are still in testing phase. @koala_dev

Comment: The problem with this (this seems like a jQuery Mobile problem), is that jQM removes the `ui-btn-active` class on some event (probably `pageshow`) so what you see is the button turn active on click, become inactive briefly on page show, and then become active again.  It definitely messes up the effect of seamless visual continuity.

Comment: @user1167442 navbar widget is still not mature, JQM team is refactoring it. Also, it may be a problem related to external fixed toolbars, which a new added feature in 1.4

Comment: I created a work-around that fixed it.  I restyled `ui-btn-active` to look identical to `ui-navbar ui-btn-a`, then I created a class called `btn-active1` and added it both on `pagebeforeshow`, and `pageshow`.  It works flawlessly.  It just happens that on this project, I don't need `ui-btn-active` anywhere else, so the workaround is easy here.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue for links in the navbar. It was very frustrating. I fired up firebug and debugged jqm. I ended up patching the jquery mobile code like so:

In jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js

From:

```
$navbtns.removeClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
activeBtn.addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
```

To:

```
if ( !($navbtns.filter( ".ui-state-persist" ) ) ) {
    $navbtns.removeClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
    activeBtn.addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
}
```

I minified jqm here: http://jscompress.com/